# What is the difference between preprocess and precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the difference between preprocess and precompile in assets pipeline of the ruby on rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprocess - a process that transforms your code into either css, html or js before you sent it to your browser. This is usually when you use (redundant here) preprocessors such as coffeescript, erb, scss, etc. I must say that the order is important when using preprocess.

Precompile - happens before you send your code to production using `rake assets:precompile`. It makes sure your code is compilable (made up word) and put them in `public/assets`

If you want more info, a quick google search can return multiple of articles. Here is [one](http://www.sitepoint.com/asset-precompile-works-part/)